# How is periodic potential approximation justified in semiconductor physics?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, crystals

In semiconductor physics the usual approximation is that of infinite crystal. This seems to allow one to write Hamiltonian for electron subsystem (in adiabatic approximation) as having periodic potential created by nuclei. But, as I've tried to plot how such a potential would look like, I was surprised to see that increasing the number of nuclei doesn't lead to convergence to a periodic potential. Instead it globally looks like a parabolic potential, with local features like Coulomb singularity. Here's a plot of 1D cross-section of 3D cubic nuclear lattice potential:

[image]

But in this case we can no longer say that the potential is actually even similar to a periodic one. This shouldn't actually surprise us, because in the limit of continuous nuclear charge the potential should become parabolic. So, how is periodicity approximation justified?

I can think of the following reasons:

- The combination of nuclear charge and lattice constant makes the parabola curvature small, so that the potential is approximately periodic across hundreds and more of lattice cells
- Or, if the above is wrong, then due to mean field approximation, we end up with an effective potential for a single effective electron, for which the whole crystal looks like a unit positive charge smeared across infinite number of nuclear sites, thus the curvature of parabolic potential appears infinitesimal, and we recover periodic potential

Which if these explanations is correct, if any? If none, then what is the correct justification?

Comment: I think you've mainly shown that 10 atoms on a line do not represent an infinite crystal potential.  Redo the calculation, steadily increasing the number of atoms, and the central portion will start looking regular.  The edges will, of course, always have edge effects.

Comment: @JonCuster no, you're fooled by the picture. There're actually $36\times36\times36$ atoms, and the picture, as I said, is a cross-section of this lattice, showing only $10$ inner atoms. Increasing atoms count further doesn't visibly affect the picture.

Comment: Start by doing it in 1D. @joncuster's comment still stands.

Comment: Also from the graph it looks like your ions are too close together so you might not see your effect until you increase the number significantly. What is normally done is to start with two ions and observe the asymptotic, and then bring another ion closer. Then you repeat the process. Maybe reduce your coulombs constant in your plot.

Comment: @lionelbrits I did start it from 1D, but there it converges to parabola-like shape obviously, since the potential of nucleus at site $a$ is $\sim|x-a|$. The result is not surprising actually, one shouldn't expect a flat periodic potential — in the limit of continuous charge distribution the potential won't be periodic too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further consideration, I think that your second solution is probably closer to the truth. We are told that the potential is due to an array of ionic cores, not necessarily point charges. So there has to be some assumption of screening. Basically the offset of the overall potential amounts to the work function, and the periodicity of the potential is assumed, and then shown to be self consistent. This is especially important because we need to solve the electron wave function in order to find $V(x)$, a la Born-Oppenheimer.

In 3d, we should expect the unscreened potential to grow as $r^2$ around any point, as predicted by Gauss's law, and this is what you are finding. I think therefore screening is important, because the crystal is really neutral. The very crudest mean field approximation would be to subtract the potential that Gauss's law predict for a uniformly charged sphere around your origin.